# How to hide elements with Jquery if PHP variable is set

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, variables, hide

I've got this piece of script, and I'm trying to hide two divs (#black and #yname) if a certain variable or session is set in PHP, so is there a simple way to do so?
Here's my code:

input.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<style type="text/css">
@import "stil.css";
</style>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jq.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="postme.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="chat">
<div id="main">
</div>
<div id="input">
<form name="form"action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="tekst" id="msg" size="72" />
<input type="submit" name="dugme" value="posalji" id="dugme" />
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="black">
</div>
<div id="yname">
<form name="yname">
<input type="text" name="tekst2" />
<input type="button" name="dugme2" value="Enter" onclick="send()"/> 
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

postme.js

```
function send(){
$.post('sesion.php',{name:yname.tekst2.value},function(val){

    }
});
}
```

sesion.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$data=$_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['name']=$data;
$sesion_n=$_SESSION['name'];
echo $sesion_n;
?>
```

So basically, what I want to do is to check if $sesion_n variable is set, and if it's set, I want my send() function to hide divs #black and #yname.

In addition, is there a way to use val value with jquery somehow for example to alert it or to assign that value to a javascript variable?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you using the spelling 'sesion' because that's how it's spelled in a language other than English? I see things like this all the time, and I'm wondering why it happens, when you can spell the global $_SESSION correctly.

Comment: Your $sesion_n variable will always be set because you're setting it in the request.

Comment: @ Frank Crook It's rather simple, I'm not a native English speaker, therefore I'm not that good at spelling, so I can easily misspell something, so I'm trying to keep my variables similar to my native language

Comment: @Jivings I guess, so but is there a way for me to check and display the exact value of that variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function send(){
   $.post('sesion.php',{name:yname.tekst2.value},function(val){
            if(val) {
                $('#black').hide();
                $('#yname').hide();  
            }

        }
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but nothing happens when I click my button.

Comment: Is it sending the POST request? You can check using firebug or Chrome development window.

Comment: It seems that POST request isn't sent, the Chrome development window gives me this message:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
sendpostme.js:2
(anonymous function)input.php:32
onclick

Comment: I've found a solution, apparently the problem was that my form had a name yname and the parent div had the yname as the id, so that was the problem, and after changing div's id to name everything works as a charm.
Anyway, your answer was most helpful, so I'll accept it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

well i didnt get your question completely but you can use **hide()** method to hide any div in jquery...

Comment: I want to hide the elements if val variable is set(preferably it has a certain value), and in addition, I was wondering is there a way to use the val variable with Javascript to alert it or use it in a equation.